# WxPython, change Frame style

Tags: python, coding-style, wxpython

```
class Window (wx.MiniFrame):
def __init__ ( self ):
    wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Mini') 
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    (...)
```

Can I/How to edit MiniFrame style

f.e. in my method ChangeStyle(), I want to make a MiniFrame with new parameter (style = wx.NO_BORDER)

Do I have to kill the window and run them again?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the frame's SetWindowStyle or SetWindowStyleFlag methods and see if they work. If not, then you'll probably have to close the frame and recreate it with the styles you want.